# scala implicit method with multiple arguments

Tags: scala, implicit

In a comment for [SIP-13](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html) Martin Odersky implied that it is possible to create an implicit method with multiple arguments. According to my experiences, implicit methods always have exactly one argument and I cannot imagine how an implicit method with multiple arguments can be used. Can someone give some use case and explanation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can implicits with multiple inputs be used in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416733/how-can-implicits-with-multiple-inputs-be-used-in-scala)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example if you need an implicit parameter of a function type:

```
implicit def foo(x: Int, y: Int) = y * x

def bar(x: Int, y: Int)(implicit f: (Int, Int) => Int) = f(x,y)

scala> bar(3,4)
res3: Int = 12
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416733/how-can-implicits-with-multiple-inputs-be-used-in-scala).